# WPF 3D perfomance issue due to low graphics card memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, 3d, gpu

My project uses 3D flip animations to show the forms. My problem is that the transitions are very slow in an XP machine. I checked the graphics card memory and its only 64MB. Does upgrading the graphics card make any difference in the perfomance?

Comment: "Only" 64MB of memory on the graphics card. Heh, heh. Kids these days... But seriously, if you're not running 3D rotating animated fractals on the desktop background, that ought to be enough space to run an animation or two.

Comment: @mjfgates: it's not really the memory that's going to be the issue - but a 64MB card indicates an older card that's likely not capable enough for some WPF rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may make some difference, but there are other alternatives to manage UI performance if your app is intended for wider distribution.

Often, software rendering will outperform hardware on lower-end machines.  This can be enabled (for ALL WPF apps) using a registry setting [detailed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx).

Additionally, WPF exposes a property that broadly categorises a machine's performance into three "tiers."  Information on those can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx).  You can expose this value as a property (say, on your `App` object) and use it in a Xaml trigger to selectively disable animations or high-end effects (shadows/blurs/etc) that might cause issues on slower machines.

On XP you may find that both of these are of benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just upgrading the graphics card that **could** benefit your application.

[WPF doesn't run optimal on Windows XP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2007/01/05/comparing-wpf-on-windows-vista-v-windows-xp.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check several things: For rendering Tier 2 DirectX version: must be greater than or equal to 9.0. Video RAM: must be greater than or equal to 120MB. Pixel shader : version level must greater than or equal to 2.0. You should take look on Graphics Rendering Tiers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx